# Referencing child object not saving

Tags: class, scheduled-apex

I'm trying to reference the product2 name from an opportunity record. However it's giving me this error and not allowing me to save the code. "Invalid foreign key relationship: Opportunity.opportunitylineitem"

How should I be referencing this field?

```
global class OpOwnerOldService_Scheduled Implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        sendEmailtoOppOwner();
    }

    public void sendEmailtoOppOwner()
    {
        List<Opportunity> listOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
        listOpportunity = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id In (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2.Make_unavailable_for_opps_and_proposals__c = TRUE)];

        for(Opportunity opp : listOpportunity)
        {
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            mail.setTargetObjectId(opp.OwnerId);
            mail.setReplyTo('glenn.daly@live.com');
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
            mail.setSubject('Historic Service attached to current opportunity : ' + opp.opportunitylineitem.Product2.Name );
            mail.setPlainTextBody(opportunity.Id +' has been created.');
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }

        update listOpportunity;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access the child record using a dot operator, as there can be multiple child records the dot operator will never find which record to access even if there is only one record.
Instead you do a inner query and use it.

```
listOpportunity = [
        SELECT Id, OwnerId, (
                SELECT Product2.Name
                FROM OpportunityLineItems
                LIMIT 1
        )
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Id IN (
                SELECT OpportunityId
                FROM OpportunityLineItem
                WHERE Product2.Make_unavailable_for_opps_and_proposals__c = TRUE
        )
];

for (Opportunity opp : listOpportunity) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    mail.setTargetObjectId(opp.OwnerId);
    mail.setReplyTo('glenn.daly@live.com');
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
    for (opportunitylineitem oppLineItem : opp.opportunitylineitems) {
        mail.setSubject('Historic Service attached to current opportunity : ' + oppLineItem.Name);
    }
}

mail.setPlainTextBody(opportunity.Id + ' has been created.');
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{
        mail
});
}
```

Please try this

Comment: Thanks @maruf but I received the following error "Didn't understand relationship 'OpportunityLineItem' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

Comment: Yeah! My bad there will be "OpportunityLineItems" in the inner query. I have updated the query please try now

Comment: The only change I needed to make to the code was adding the Id field when querying the opportunity line items, apart from that it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That was good to know. Always happy to help :)